# SQL syntax error - Haversine formula

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to [get nearest places](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645490/get-nearest-places-google-maps-mysql-spatial-data/4979891) from a WordPress database using [Haversine formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

My table structure below

**posts**

```
+--------------+
| Field        |
+--------------+
| ID           |
| post_author  |
| post_title   | 
| post_type    | 
+--------------+
```

**postmeta**

```
+--------------+
| Field        |
+--------------+
| meta_id      |
| post_id      |
| meta_key     |
| meta_value   |
+--------------+
```

and have records with `meta_key` values `latitude` and `longitude`

See the [answer to my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249724/selecting-a-join-tables-column-values-as-result-column-name) for the SQL I've used to get the latitude and longitude.

```
SELECT p.ID, 
  p.post_title, 
  p.post_author,
  max(case when pm.meta_key='latitude' then pm.meta_value end) latitude,
  max(case when pm.meta_key='longitude' then pm.meta_value end) longitude
FROM `wp_posts` p
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` pm
  on p.ID=pm.post_id 
WHERE p.post_type='place' 
  AND (pm.meta_key='latitude' OR pm.meta_key='longitude') 
GROUP BY p.ID, p.post_title, p.post_author
ORDER BY p.ID ASC
```

Now I want to incorporate above query into [answer for this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4645490/get-nearest-places-google-maps-mysql-spatial-data/4979891#4979891)

```
SELECT item1, item2, 
    ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(37) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lat ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( lng ) 
                       - radians(-122) ) 
                   + sin( radians(37) ) 
                   * sin( radians( lat ) ) 
                 )
   ) AS distance 
FROM geocodeTable 
HAVING distance < 25 
ORDER BY distance LIMIT 0 , 20;
```

Below is by combined query

```
SELECT ID, 
  post_title, 
  post_author,
  max(case when meta_key='latitude' then meta_value end) latitude,
  max(case when meta_key='longitude' then meta_value end) longitude,
  ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(18.204540500000) ) 
                   * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( longitude ) 
                       - radians(-66.450958500000) ) 
                   + sin( radians(18.204540500000 ) 
                   * sin( radians( latitude ) ) 
                 )
   ) AS distance 
FROM `wp_posts` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` 
  on ID=post_id 
WHERE post_type='place' 
  AND (meta_key='latitude' OR meta_key='longitude') 
GROUP BY ID, post_title, post_author
ORDER BY ID ASC
```

But this yields syntax error

```
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS distance FROM `wp_posts` LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` on ID=post_id WHERE po' at line 13
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing a closing `)` for the first `sin()`

```
( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(18.204540500000) ) 
                   * cos( radians( latitude ) ) 
                   * cos( radians( longitude ) 
                       - radians(-66.450958500000) ) 
                   + sin( radians(18.204540500000 ) ) /* <--- here */
                   * sin( radians( latitude ) ) 
              )
 ) AS distance
```

Though it is difficult to spot visually, I found this by copying your code into a text editor that supports brace matching. It is highly recommended to use one, if not for query development and testing, then at least for debugging.

Comment: I was using MySQL Workbench, but it does not have brace matching :-(

Comment: @mithun does this query provide you result.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT *, ( 3959 * ACOS( COS( RADIANS(18.204540500000) ) 
                   * COS( RADIANS( latitude ) ) 
                   * COS( RADIANS( longitude ) 
                       - RADIANS(-66.450958500000) ) 
                   + SIN( RADIANS(18.204540500000 ) )
                   * SIN( RADIANS( latitude ) ) 
                 )
   ) AS distance  
FROM 
(SELECT ID, 
  post_title, 
  post_author,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='geo_latitude' THEN meta_value END) latitude,
  MAX(CASE WHEN meta_key='geo_longitude' THEN meta_value END) longitude
FROM `wp_posts` 
LEFT JOIN `wp_postmeta` 
  ON ID=post_id 
WHERE post_type='place' 
  AND (meta_key='geo_latitude' OR meta_key='geo_longitude') 
GROUP BY ID, post_title, post_author
ORDER BY ID ASC) AS A
```